# how to retrieve data using result set and send to jsp one by one at a time

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is example code,

```
 //Servlet Code
 while (results.next()) {                                            
     out.print(results.getString(1));
 }
```

I'm using **ajax**, Here the response send the whole output to the jsp. If result set contains 100 records it executes until the end of the loop and send whole output as response.

But I want to get one by one record and send it to the jsp (get the first record --> send it to the jsp, second record-->send it to the jsp .....) and in the jsp the records show in a dynamic table. The client could show loading data to the table row by row.

If anyone can help me

Comment: can you tell me clearly, for what purpose u want this

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want do do that, this would 1/ generates too much network traffic for nothing (unless maybe with some web socket), 2/ keep a DB connection open for nothing. My advice, read the 100 lines, send that to the client and if you really want some loading effect, *fake* that client side.

Comment: Hi karthik, thanks alt for your consideration :), here is my purpose. in the  servlet I retrieve about 50000 records and it sends to the jsp and it is done by ajax. issue is when client open the page he has to wait until retrieve all the records and it takes about 10-15 seconds. then client don't know how long will it takes to load the data. what i was trying to do is when load the jsp, data load one by one into the table. then client can see loading the data.. clear the problem?? if you have any idea how to do it ? or do you know any other ways please let me know.. :) big help..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer might misunderstand in your question somehow, but this is what I understand by reading your question. First you said...

> get the first record --> send it to the jsp, second record-->send it to the jsp .....

then you also said that...

> The client could show loading data to the table row by row

It is seems like you want to implement lazy loading on your page to fetch your data dynamically like Facebook and Twitter does. I never done this before, since I often use [pagination](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jsp/pagination-in-servlet-and-jsp/). I know there are more proper tutorial site for this, but this is quick example what I found when I search on Google, [here](https://responsivedesign.is/resources/javascript-jquery/lazy-load).

Comment: Thank you Amin for your reply :)  here is my purpose. in the  servlet I retrieve about 50000 records and it sends to the jsp and it is done by ajax. issue is when client open the page he has to wait until retrieve all the records and it takes about 10-15 seconds. then client don't know how long will it takes to load the data. what i was trying to do is when load the jsp, data load one by one into the table. then client can see loading the data.. besides i want to print the table then i cannot use the pagination and sure, I'll refer lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly printing the record, print it inside the td tags.

So, your code becomes something like this:

```
out.print("<table><thead><th>My Title</th></thead>");
while (results.next()) {
 out.print("<tr><td>");                                            
 out.print(results.getString(1));
 out.print("</td></tr>");
}
out.print("</table>");
```

If you want show loading of the table dynamically, add your resultset as a TreeMap into your request object. While printing in the jsp add delay.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Viraj :) this is interesting, actually i want to load the table dynamically when send the out put from servlet. ok i'll check with this treemap, i have never used it before. i'll let u know if i got any issue. pls help me :) thanks a lot..

Comment: In treemap, you can store the row number and objects retrieved from resultset  as a map. The treemap is always sorted and hence your data would be in same row order in which you have stored. If you have only one string object in your treemap, you can go with a simple ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks friend. It worked :D. As u said i used treemap. Now the table is loading dynamically as i wished :) Again thanks alot n Happy New Year 2016 :D